Flutter MobileScanner - camera zoomed on ios issue
I am using flutter package = MobileScanner to scan qr code
In the UI there is a button that triggers camera open based on state condition
then on opening the qr scanner a small camera popup screen appears which scan the qr code that allows user to clock in.
the code can be demonstrated as follow:
class _QRClockUIState extends State<QRClockUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(widget.clockedIn ? Icons.stop : Icons.play_arrow,
                size: 30),
            label: Text(
              widget.clockedIn ? 'STOP SHIFT' : 'START SHIFT',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              if (widget.clockedIn) {
                widget.handleShift(Map<String, dynamic>());
              } else {
                _showQRScanner();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showQRScanner() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        double dialogWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6;
        double dialogHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5;
        return Dialog(
          child: Container(
            width: dialogWidth,
            height: dialogHeight,
            child: MobileScanner(
              fit: BoxFit.none,
              onDetect: (barcodes) {
                if (barcodes.barcodes[0].rawValue != null) {
                  print('QR Code: ${barcodes.barcodes[0].rawValue}');
                  // Parse the JSON from the rawValue
                  Map<String, dynamic> data =
                      jsonDecode(barcodes.barcodes[0].rawValue ?? '{}');
                  print('data: $data');
                  widget.handleShift(data);

                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

the camera popup that opens looks fine on android phone but it gets zoomed automatically on ios whats the problem..
